# PHP variable not showing in email?

Tags: php

In the following code the variable $filedownload should be a link. It wont show when called outside of folder singleuse.
When i do a similar script inside singleuse folder and change remove folder from include code, then it displays. I guess it might be todo with the include call? 
I would like to call the variable from outside the folder.

I tested the variable and it has a value. its just not showing up on the email.

```html
<?php
/**
 * This file creates the single use download link
 * The query string should be the password (which is set in variables.php)
 * If the password fails, then 404 is rendered
 *
 * Expects: generate.php?1234
 */
 include("variables.php");

 // Grab the query string as a password
 $password = '1234';
 
 /*
  * Verify the admin password (in variables.php)
  */ 
 if($password == ADMIN_PASSWORD) {
  // Create a new key
  $new = uniqid('key',TRUE);
  
  /*
   * Create a protected directory to store keys in
   */
  if(!is_dir('keys')) {
   mkdir('keys');
   $file = fopen('keys/.htaccess','w');
   fwrite($file,"Order allow,deny\nDeny from all");
   fclose($file);
  }
  
  /*
   * Write the key key to the keys list
   */
  $file = fopen('keys/keys','a');
  fwrite($file,"{$new}\n");
  fclose($file);
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Download created</title>
  <style>
   nl { 
    font-family: monospace 
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Payment Success</h1>
  <?php 
   $filedownload = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . DOWNLOAD_PATH . "?" . $new; 
  ?>
 </body>
</html>

<?php
 } else {
  /*
   * Someone stumbled upon this link with the wrong password
   * Fake a 404 so it does not look like this is a correct path
   */
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
 }
?>
```

```
include('/singleuse/generate.php');

$mail_From = "From: me@mybiz.com";
$mail_To = "savisaar2@gmail.com";
$mail_Subject = "VERIFIED IPN";
$mail_Body = "Hello there, thank you for purchasing from us. \nPlease go to: " . $filedownload;

mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, "\n\n" . $mail_Body, $mail_From);
```

Comment: Print the `$filedownload` variable and see that it surely is a link.

Comment: Please give us the code snippet where $fileDownload gets its value and the code snippet where you pass this variable to the code from the question. Otherwise we can't help you, as there are plenty of possible reasons for your code to not work.

Comment: I have added the generate.php

Comment: I have tested the variable and it works .. im not sure here

Answer (score 1):

In a last effort i decided i would try to use a different php script for email, and it worked!

```html
if ($payment_status == 'Completed') {
       include('singleuse/generate.php');
       
       $to      = 'savisaar2@gmail.com';
       $subject = 'Transation Completed [Ref #' . $txn_id . ']';
       $message = 'Thank you ' . $payer_email . '! Your payment status is: ' . $payment_status . ', your order number is #' . $txn_id . '. Please follow this link to get your download: ' . $filedownload;
       $headers = 'From: webmaster@dev4you.hints.me' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: webmaster@dev4you.hints.me' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

       mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```